# How to send keys to Ionic 4 input with Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am using Ionic 4 (beta) and am unsure what the best (/easiest) way is to send keys to an input field using Appium.

Ionic HTML code:

```
<form>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">E-mail</ion-label>
        <ion-input [formControl]="email" id="sign-in-email-input" type="email" autofocus="true"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

In my appium test I want to send keys to this input. I notice in Chrome dev tools that below the ion-input a native input is created by Ionic, which is in a shadow dom. So -after some googling- I go after it like this:

```py
email = driver.find_element_by_id('sign-in-email-input')
jsCommand = "return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('input');"
emailNative = driver.execute_script(jsCommand, email)
emailNative.send_keys('test@test.com')
```

But the send_keys command throws "StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM".

I'm going around this by doing:

```py
email = driver.find_element_by_id('sign-in-email-input')
jsCommand = "arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('input').value = 'test@test.com';"
driver.execute_script(jsCommand, email)
```

That seems to work at first (I see the value appear in the IOS simulator). But when focus moves to another field, the value disappears.

What is the correct way to send keys with Appium to an input in Ionic 4?